# Postgres query to return all outcomes from a user

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

At the moment when marking a student's evidence, all I am displaying is a list of outcomes. The assessors (in charge of marking students evidence) would like to know if the outcome has already been partially or fully met.

I have been working in a SQL query that returns a students outcomes and whether they have been partially or fully met.

- Students have many evidence
- evidences have many evidence_outcomes
- evidences have many outcomes, through evidence_outcomes
- evidence_outcome belongs_to evidence
- evidence_outcome belongs_to outcome
- students have many units, through enrollent_units
- units have many outcomes

For each outcome I have to:
get the outcome content, check if there are any evidence_outcomes that belong_to the students' evidence (that are partially met for that outcome) and finally check if there are any evidence_outcomes that belong_to the students' evidence (that are fully met for that outcome)

My schema is: the following:

```
# Table name: company_students
#
#  id                        :bigint           not null, primary key

has_many :evidences
has_many :units, through: :enrolled_units,
================

# Table name: company_student_enrolled_units
#
#  id         :bigint           not null, primary key
#  completed  :boolean          default(FALSE)
#  student_id :integer
#  unit_id    :integer

belongs_to :student
belongs_to :unit
================

# Table name: curriculum_evidences
#
#  id                     :bigint           not null, primary key
#  description            :text
#  title                  :string
#  assigned_coursework_id :integer
#  student_id             :integer

has_many evidences_outcomes
has_many outcomes through evidence_outcomes
================

# Table name: curriculum_outcomes
#
#  id               :bigint           not null, primary key
#  code             :text
#  content          :text
#  position         :integer
#  outcome_group_id :integer
#  unit_id          :integer

has_many :evidence_outcomes
has_many :evidences through evidence_outcomes
================


# Table name: curriculum_evidence_outcomes
#
#  id               :bigint           not null, primary key
#  meets_outcome    :boolean          default(FALSE)
#  partially_met    :boolean          default(FALSE)
#  curriculum_id    :integer
#  enrolled_unit_id :integer
#  evidence_id      :integer
#  outcome_id       :integer
#  student_id       :integer

belongs_to :evidence
belongs_to :outcome
================
```

Have tried modifying my joins, with no success

```
SELECT DISTINCT CASE WHEN partially_met='f'
  THEN 'True'
  ELSE 'False'
END AS Partially_met,
co.id AS outcome_id,
co.unit_id,
co.content,
students.id AS student_id

FROM company_students AS students

JOIN curriculum_evidences
  AS ce
  ON students.id = ce.student_id

LEFT JOIN curriculum_evidence_outcomes ceo
       ON ce.id =  ceo.evidence_id

LEFT JOIN curriculum_outcomes
       AS co
       ON co.id=ceo.outcome_id

LEFT JOIN curriculum_evidences
       AS cev
       ON cev.student_id=ceo.student_id

WHERE students.id = 901
ORDER BY co.content asc
```

I have limited knowledge in SQL and my query is Just returning outcomes that a student (student 901 in this example) has relations to it, but I would like to get all of the outcomes,

Comment: You question is very difficult to understand. What do you mean, "I would like to get all of the outcomes"? You don't have an `Outcome` model. Do you mean you would like to get all the curriculum outcomes? Because you do have a `CurriculumOutcome` model. If you literally want all of them, then do `CurriculumOutcome.all`. But, I suspect that's not the answer you're looking for. Or is it?

Comment: If the query works for student 901, then if you want results for **all** students, just remove `WHERE students.id = 901`?